# PHP function to display outside

Tags: php, function

header.php

```
 <div class="banner">
   <?php
     function slider($url) {
          echo '<img src="' . $url . '" />';
     }
 </div>
```

body.php

```
<?php
 include('header.php');
 slider('http://google.com/myimage.png');
?>
```

Now it echo the slider inside body.. while I need to echo it inside Header..
But I need only define each banner inside body so it will be different..

Unable to think what i can do with it

Comment: It doesn't work that way. The funciton is executed after </div>. I recommend you set a variable and pass it in to the header.php, which directly shows your banner.

Comment: If i do echo $banner and then define $banner = "abc.jpg" in body it says undefined variable

Comment: Put the `<div class="banner">` *inside* the `slider` function...!?

Answer (score 0):

At the point that you `include('header.php')` in `body.php` all of the code in `header.php` is executed. Any plain HTML is just echoed out in place, and the function you have becomes defined but is not executed until you call it after all of `header.php`has been completed.

To fix this you can define a variable in `body.php` before you include `header.php`. Inside of `header.php` check for the existence of that variable and if it exists display the proper HTML.

header.php:

```
<?php
if ($banner_url) {
    echo '<div class="banner">';
    echo '<img src="' . $banner_url . '" />';
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

body.php:

```
<?php
$banner_url = 'http://www.example.com/';
include('header.php');
?>
```